# Restructuing the code structure is giving me an include issue in php

Tags: php, path, include

I restructured my already working code. My earlier directory structure was as follows:

- web

  - css

    - style.css
  - model

    - db_functions.inc
  - view

    - view_functions.inc
  - controller
  - index.php

Here is the code snippet which was working:

```
<?php
    $pageTitle = "Citee.me";

    //include view functions
    include ('view/view_functions.inc');
    //incldue db functions
    include ('model/db_functions.inc');
    doHtmlHeader($pageTitle);
    doBody();
    testMySQL();
    doHtmlFooter();
?>
```

I now restructured the code to be:

- web

  - model

    - db_functions.inc
  - view

    - view_functions.inc
  - controller
- public

  - css

    - style.css
  - js
  - images
  - index.php

Now I modified my index.php code to be as follows (i commented out the db functions to narrow down the problem):

```
 <?php
    $pageTitle = "Citee.me";

    //include view functions
    include ('/citee/web/view/view_functions.inc');
    //incldue db functions
    //include ('./model/db_functions.inc');
    doHtmlHeader($pageTitle);
    //doBody();
    //testMySQL();
    doHtmlFooter();
?>
```

I get the error:

```
PHP Warning:  include(/citee/web/view/view_functions.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/citee/public/index.php on line 6

PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/citee/web/view/view_functions.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in /Library/WebServer/Documents/citee/public/index.php on line 6

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function doHtmlHeader() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/citee/public/index.php on line 9
```

Not sure why I am getting this error. Is my include path wrong? I tried different combinations but did not help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHP complains that the path `/citee/web/view/view_functions.inc` doesn't exist, and I also doubt it. Can you `cd /citee/web/view/`? I bet not.

If you are trying to access it, you can do it (and is a better practice, thinking about future deployments to different structured server file-systems in the future) with a relative file path.

So, instead of `/citee/web/view/view_functions.inc`, you can work from the path of index.php toward the correct relative path: `../web/view/view_functions.inc` (`..` stands for "go up a directory in the tree", meaning it will go into your "citee" folder, and then access the "web" folder, and so on.)

Answer (score 7):

PHP is your friend, it gave you the full path to where your code is being executed from:

`/Library/WebServer/Documents/citee/`

not

`/citee/`

Just because you can't access the files outside of your web root doesn't mean PHP doesn't look outside of your web root.

Comment: +1 - to sum up, what animuson is saying here is that you need to clarify whether your paths are relative or absolute. If you are using relative paths, remove the leading `/` from the path.

Comment: I used the realtive path ../web/view/view_functions.inc and it worked. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 3):

In the second example, your paths are absolute and start with "/citee". But the error messages show that your files are at "/Library/WebServer/Documents/citee". If you are using an absolute path, you must use the correct one.